# Некорректная сортировка

Tags: c++

Не сортируются числовые значения, остаются на своих местах.
Когда сортирую фамилии по алфавиту, то айдишник и остальное остается на своих прежних местах при выводе на экран, есть мысли почему они не перемещаются с фамилией? SWAP тоже не работает...

```
void SortingBySourname()
{
    ifstream reading("Data.txt");

    int n = 0, temp = 0;

    int arr_ID[100]{};
    int arr_KV[100]{};
    int arr_Floors[100]{};

    string arr_Surname[100];

    bool flag = true;

    reading >> n;

    if (reading)
    {
        // чтение данных из файла и сохранение в массивы
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            reading >> arr_ID[i];
            reading >> arr_KV[i];
            reading >> arr_Floors[i];
            reading >> arr_Surname[i];
        }

        do
        {
            flag = true;
            sort(arr_Surname, arr_Surname + n);

            for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
            {
                if (arr_Surname[i].compare(arr_Surname[i + 1]) > 0)
                {
                    swap(arr_Surname[i], arr_Surname[i + 1]);
                    flag = false;
                    
                    if(flag)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
                        {
                            temp = arr_ID[i];
                            arr_ID[i] = arr_ID[i + 1];
                            arr_ID[i + 1] = temp;

                            temp = arr_KV[i];
                            arr_KV[i] = arr_KV[i + 1];
                            arr_KV[i + 1] = temp;

                            temp = arr_Floors[i];
                            arr_Floors[i] = arr_Floors[i + 1];
                            arr_Floors[i + 1] = temp;
                        }
                    }
                    
                    // swap(arr_ID[i], arr_ID[i + 1]);
                    // swap(arr_KV[i], arr_KV[i + 1]);
                    // swap(arr_Floors[i], arr_Floors[i + 1]);
                    
                }
            }
        } while (!flag);

        // вывод данных
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            cout << "ID: " << arr_ID[i] << endl;
            cout << "кв.м: " << arr_KV[i] << endl;
            cout << "Этажность: " << arr_Floors[i] << endl;
            cout << "Фамилия: " << arr_Surname[i] << endl;
            cout << "____________________________________________\n" << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: И что вы тут делаете: `sort(arr_Surname, arr_Surname + n);`? Перемещаете элементы `arr_Surname`, так что они больше не соответствуют остальным полям... Кстати, зачем? А вообще, используйте структуры, а не растаскивайте информацию по разным массивам...

Comment: @Harry Да вообще тут код "красивый" ))  Например вот это: `flag = false; if(flag) ...` )))

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

struct House {
    int id;
    size_t area;
    size_t floors;
    std::string owner;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const House&);
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const House& other) {
    out << "House(";
    out << "id: " << other.id << "; ";
    out << "area: " << other.area << "; ";
    out << "floors: " << other.floors << "; ";
    out << "owner: " << other.owner << ')';
    return out;
}

char print(House* arr, size_t len) {
    std::cout << '[';
    if(len) {
        std::cout << arr[0];
        for(size_t i = 1; i < len; ++i)
            std::cout << ", " << arr[i];
    }
    std::cout << ']';
    return '\0';
}

class Comparator {
public:
    bool operator()(const House& h1, const House& h2) {
        return h1.owner.compare(h2.owner) < 0;
    }
};

House* scan(const std::string& data_path, size_t& n) {
    House* arr = nullptr;
    std::ifstream ifs(data_path);

    if(!ifs.is_open()) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Can not open the file: " + data_path);
    }

    ifs >> n;
    arr = new House[n];
    for(size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        ifs >> arr[i].id;
        ifs >> arr[i].area;
        ifs >> arr[i].floors;
        ifs >> arr[i].owner;
    }

    ifs.close();
    return arr;
}

int main() {
    size_t n;
    House* arr;
    arr = scan("Data.txt", n);

    std::cout << "Initial Array: " << print(arr, n) << '\n';
    std::sort(arr, arr + n, Comparator());
    std::cout << "Sorted Array: " << print(arr, n) << '\n';

    delete[] arr;
    return 0;
}
```

**Data.txt:**

```
4
-3 5 10 Ivanov
0 10 5 Sidorov
231 6 6 Petrov
8 10 10 Ivanov
```

**Вывод:**

```
Initial Array: [House(id: -3; area: 5; floors: 10; owner: Ivanov), House(id: 0; area: 10; floors: 5; owner: Sidorov), House(id: 231; area: 6; floors: 6; owner: Petrov), House(id: 8; area: 10; floors: 10; owner: Ivanov)]
Sorted Array: [House(id: -3; area: 5; floors: 10; owner: Ivanov), House(id: 8; area: 10; floors: 10; owner: Ivanov), House(id: 231; area: 6; floors: 6; owner: Petrov), House(id: 0; area: 10; floors: 5; owner: Sidorov)]
```